# Can't link variable inside a switch when creating a new block

Tags: ev3, programming, motor

I have a problem when connecting the variable (from the create a block) to a variable in the function because it's inside a switch. How can I link them?
[image]

I want to connect the variable to each (20) in the motor blocks

Answer (score 2):

Using variables is probably a better solution, but you can pass data wires into a switch block if it is tabbed view.

Answer (score 1):

To get technical, this thing (pictured below) is a "parameter", not a "variable".

[image: screenshot of my block parameter]

"Variables" look like this:

[image]

You can use a data wire to write the parameter value to a variable *before* the switch block and then read the variable inside of the nested switch blocks. Something like this...

[image]